# Getting lodash errors with Visual Composer and Mega Menu in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm running Wordpress 5.1, with Bridge Theme version 7.2 and WP Bakery Page Builder version 5.7. I try to go into my backend editor to add a new row with WP Bakery/Visual Composer. When i click the "+" sign at the top, nothing happens.

I check the developer console to see what might be the issue and I get this error:

```
> backend.min.js?ver=5.7:1 Uncaught TypeError: _.contains is not a
> function
>     at backend.min.js?ver=5.7:1
>     at 9.6df36390bab8dded22f6.js:9
>     at 9.6df36390bab8dded22f6.js:9
>     at Ve (9.6df36390bab8dded22f6.js:9)
>     at 9.6df36390bab8dded22f6.js:9
>     at vr (9.6df36390bab8dded22f6.js:9)
>     at Function.pe.reduce (9.6df36390bab8dded22f6.js:9)
>     at N.d.<anonymous> (backend.min.js?ver=5.7:1)
>     at N.d.c [as _getNotIn] (underscore.min.js:1)
>     at N.d.buildFiltering (backend.min.js?ver=5.7:1)
```

I run into a similar issue when using Max Mega Menu Plugin (Version 2.5.3.2). When I add a gallery, I don't actually have the option to add the gallery. I get the following error in the console:

```
media-gallery-widget.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: _.pluck is not a function
    at N.d.updateSelectedAttachments (media-gallery-widget.min.js:1)
    at N.d.t [as updateSelectedAttachments] (9.6df36390bab8dded22f6.js:9)
    at N.d.initialize (media-gallery-widget.min.js:1)
    at N.d.b.View (backbone.min.js:1)
    at N.d [as constructor] (backbone.min.js:1)
    at new N.d (backbone.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.b.handleWidgetAdded (media-widgets.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js:3)
updateSelectedAttachments @ media-gallery-widget.min.js:1
t @ 9.6df36390bab8dded22f6.js:9
initialize @ media-gallery-widget.min.js:1
b.View @ backbone.min.js:1
N.d @ backbone.min.js:1
N.d @ backbone.min.js:1
b.handleWidgetAdded @ media-widgets.min.js:1
dispatch @ jquery.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.js:3
trigger @ jquery.js:3
a.event.trigger @ jquery-migrate.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:3
each @ jquery.js:2
each @ jquery.js:2
trigger @ jquery.js:3
(anonymous) @ admin.js?ver=2.5.3.2:463
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ admin.js?ver=2.5.3.2:462
i @ jquery.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.js:2
y @ jquery.js:4
c @ jquery.js:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery.js:4
ajax @ jquery.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:4
(anonymous) @ admin.js?ver=2.5.3.2:398
dispatch @ jquery.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.js:3
```

I noticed they both dealt with `_.function is not a function` so I'm wondering if I'm using a deprecated JavaScript library? I don't understand why though because these are the most current versions of the theme, Wordpress and Visual Composer (WP Bakery).

Has anyone run into this issue and know how to fix it?

Comment: Check version of lodash, i.e. in 4.17.11 there's no `contains` or `pluck` method https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11 , these methods are in 3.10.1 https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1

Comment: Gotcha thanks for the info. How would I go about updating this version of lodash that I have?